# verifyAlertNotPresent() in selenium ide halts the execution on failure

Tags: selenium

I have written a script to Verify that alert is not present using verifyAlertNotPresent command. Using this command as I know execution should not stop even if alert is present and should continue but it halts the execution. My script is given below.

```
forXml | file:///E:/XML files/NAA_StateZip.xml
open | 
clickAndWait | link=NAA Click & Lease
type | name=_OWNER | sdfsdf
type | name=OWNERFAX | 1234556
fireEvent | name=OWNERFAX | blur
verifyAlertNotPresent | Error: Invalid input format  Please re-enter area code and phone number | 
 close
 selectWindow |  null
 endForXml
```

When I am running this script Log shows this.

```
    [info] Executing: |type | name=OWNERFAX | 1234556 |
   [info] Executing: |fireEvent | name=OWNERFAX | blur |
   [info] Executing: |verifyAlertNotPresent | Error: Invalid input format Please re-enter area code and phone number | |
    [error] true
    [info] Executing: |close | | |
      [error] There was an unexpected Alert! [Error: Invalid input format  Please re-enter area code and phone number]
      [info] Test case fail
```

Please provide solution to this as I want to run this script for set of data.

Answer (score 0):

To handle alerts using Selenium IDE, you will have to use '***assertFoo(pattern)***' function. If you fail to assert the presence of a pop-up your next command will be blocked and you will get an error.  Look at the [Docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows).